# validates_inclusion_of Rails 3 with a query not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, client-side-validation

I am newish to Rails and i am facing a prblem. I have

Models

```
Model1
id: integer
account_id: integer

Account
id: integer
```

I have a validation in the Model1 as follows,

Model Code:

```
validates :account_id, :inclusion => { :in => Account.find(:all).collect(&:id)}
```

I use a dropdown for
View Code:

```
<%= f.select :account_id, @accounts.collect {|acc| [acc.name, acc.id]}, {:prompt => 'Select Account' }, { :selected => @defaultaccount, :class => 'selectwidth' } %>
```

I am using client side validations to validate the fields before submitting the form. I am using Heroku to deploy my app.

I create an account first and then from the form i try to create a new model1. The drop down is populated with all the accounts that i have. Then i select an account that i created from the dropdown, the client side validations comes into effect and says "is not valid" which is the error message for validates_inclusion_of as if the account never exists. Not sure what ishappening and i checked the database and the account is created which is why the dropdown is loaded with accounts in the first place.

I change the validates_inclusion_of to rails 3 validates :account_id, :inclusion => { :in => {} } syntax and redeploy. Now i try to select that account in the new model1 form, The drop down does not show an error for the account that was previously created.

So then i created a new account and tried to create a new model1 for the new account the validation failure resurfaces.

So its like a cache issue ? Is it a client side validations issue ? I did everything i can to try and find what the issues is but i am out of ideas on what is happening.

So everytime i create an account it expects me redeploy which kills what the application does. How do i get rid of this problem ? Not really sure what is happening.

Config,
Rails 3
Deployed in Heroku 
uses Asset pipeline

Gems:
Client Side Validations
Kaminari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working as you want because the  `:in => Account.find(:all).collect(&:id)` it's evaluated just one time in production mode, when Rails loads the class. I confess I don't understand the reason behind such a validation. Anyway, you have to use a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) if you really want to achieve that.

Comment: I have not given the entire logic of the validation query just for simplicity :) Well thanks for the heads up about the evaluation.

Comment: Ah OK. The evaluation problem with validations and scopes is something that can drive you mad sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the statement gets executed once the server is started (as you correctly realized). You'll need to wrap it in a lambda, so it gets executed everytime the validation is done.

1.8.7 Syntax:

```
validates :account_id, :inclusion => { :in => lambda {Account.find(:all).collect(&:id)}}
```

1.9.2 Syntax:

```
validates :account_id, :inclusion => { :in => ->{Account.find(:all).collect(&:id)]}
```

Comment: Yeah right. I forgot to mention that it's possible to use a proc or a lamba.